# OpenCV Face Verification

Tags: opencv, verification, face-recognition

Is there way that I can implement Face Recognition using OpenCV? I tried to use LBPH, and train with one image. It gives a confidence score, but I am not sure how accurate this is to use for verification.

My question is how can I create a face recognition system that tells me how similar the two faces are/if they are the same person or not using OpenCV. It doesn't seem like the confidence score is an accurate measure, if I'm doing this correctly.

Also, is a higher confidence score better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV 3 currently support following algorithms for face recognition:
- Eigenfaces (see createEigenFaceRecognizer())
- Fisherfaces (see createFisherFaceRecognizer())
- Local Binary Patterns Histograms (see createLBPHFaceRecognizer())

Confidence score by these algorithms is the similarity measure between faces, but these methods are really old and perform poorly. I'd suggest you try this article : http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2015/Parkhi15/parkhi15.pdf
Basically you need to download trained caffe model from here: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/vgg_face/src/vgg_face_caffe.tar.gz
Use opencv to run this classifier like shown is this example:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html#gsc.tab=0
Then collect fc8 feature layer of size 4096 floats from caffe network. And calculate your similarity as L2 norm between two fc8 layers calculated for your faces.